# Varnish VCL to get a header from the origin and associate it with a sessionid for future cache lookups

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

We have a number of user roles, and would like Varnish to cache the authenticated pages as many users are in each role.

In theory, we could add the role code to the request, eg, as a cookie, then strip sessionid and use that role code value in the key when storing the page in cache. But this opens a security hole, if someone copies the role code into their cookie.

Could the origin server add a header to the response with the role key, and Varnish extract it (on first delivery to that session), and associate it with a sessionid, in private, shared Varnish server memory space, and then when a future request from this session comes in, look up the role code based on sessionid, and use that to construct the cache key?

This seems secure, as Varnish only trusts the role from the origin, but is it possible?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Better use some signed cookies or JSON web tokens. I have some example code here: https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/libvmod-frozen/-/tree/master/examples/jwt

Comment: Thank you Nils. ChatGPT3 reckons we could add a key-value backend such as memcached or redis, then store sessionid -> rolecode in it. Another approach on firmer ground is redirecting to the Auth server to add the headers, then adding a restart to the request (documented [here](https://showmax.engineering/articles/achieving-a-tenfold-increase-in-varnish-throughput)). A fourth is adding mod_var and maintaining a hash lookup. I believe.. haven't started on this yet.

Comment: Signing a role id alone would not be secure, as the signed id string could still be stolen and added to a hacker's request, giving them access to private cache entries. To be secure, you'd either need to sign sessionid and role together, or sessionid and an expiry together, (done for you if using JWT). Not suggesting Nils didn't know that, just highlighting for caution. Might be wrong, happily corrected if so.

Comment: Yes, Tokens as Cookies can be transferred to other User-Agents, so the usual recommendations apply, in particular to use the `httpOnly` and `Secure` attributes. Tying them to other properties of a particular client are another option. The IP address is an obvious idea, but not reliable any more in today's internet where clients switch uplinks frequently and dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

hum... you might try to transform your varnish into an api gateway.. via the  vmod_curl (opensource). it would be easier/safer with the varnish software/entreprise modules (vmod_http and vmod_headerplus)

So the end-user is getting an authorization bearer, which might be safe.. and the varnish cache is hashed with roles (who are expected to be fewer that the users)

very roughly:

```
import curl;

vcl_recv {
   if (req.http.authorization) {

      set req.http.bearer-authorization = regsub(req.http.authorization,"^Bearer (.*)$","\1");
      if (req.http.bearer-authorization) {

           curl.header_add("Authorization:" + req.http.bearer-authorization);
           curl("https://myoauthwebsite/oauth");
           if (curl.status() == 200) {
              set http.req.x-roles = curl.body();
           }
           curl.free()
           unset req.http.bearer-authorization;
      }

      unset req.http.authorization; # without the unset, no-cache

      ...
}
vcl_hash {
   if (http.req.x-roles) {
      hash_data(http.req.x-roles);
   }
}
```

To achieve high rates, you might also put your oauth server behind your varnish configuration (so your curl would be something like curl("127.0.0.1");

As Nils explained, you might also store everything in a JWT token.

Comment: Great idea thanks, actually hadn't seen this when I added my comment, have minor concerns about performance of curl from [this article](https://showmax.engineering/articles/achieving-a-tenfold-increase-in-varnish-throughput) but we're relatively low volume so this might hit the spot. Will mark as answer once I've experimented a little.

Comment: Using `libvmod_redis` could also be an option to avoid overloading the authentication endpoint. See https://github.com/carlosabalde/libvmod-redis for more info. The roleId that is fetched from Redis could be used as an extra cache key in `vcl_hash`.